# How to drop a parquet partition with pyspark on Spark 1.5.2?

Tags: pyspark

Once we have loaded data to a praquet file partitioned on the business date as an integer format - yyyyMMdd, how do we drop the partition and facilitate reprocess of data for the same day. The overwrite mode rewrites the whole file which is already huge.

Comment: What do you want to do ?

Comment: Can you just delete the directory for yyyMMdd on disk?

Comment: Deleting the folder is not guaranteed to be the clean approach and the parquet file could end up being corrupt. The meta files generated will not be reflect the deleted partition folder. Any other options?